# Corollary of Pitt's theorem ($\ell_p$ and $\ell_q$ are mutually non isomorphic unless $p=q.$)

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

Currently I am reading [Topics in Banach space Theory by Albiac and Kalton, $2$nd edition](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319315553#aboutAuthors).

The authors provided a proof of Pitt's theorem at page $31,$ chapter $2.$

> Theorem $2.1.4$ (**Pitt's Theorem**) Suppose $1\leq p<r <\infty.$
>   If $X$ is a closed subspace of $\ell_r$ and $T:X\to \ell_p$ is a bounded linear operator, then $T$ is compact.

Straight after the proof of Pitt's theorem, the authors provided the following corollary (in between the theorem and corollary, there is a remark on the proof of Pitt's theorem, thus the numbering).

> Corollary $2.1.6$ The spaces of the set $\{c_0\}\cup \{\ell_p:1\leq p<\infty\}$ are mutually non isomorphic.
>   In fact, if $X$ is an infinite-dimensional subspace of one of the spaces $\{c_0\}\cup \{\ell_p:1\leq p<\infty\}$, then $X$ is not isomorphic to a subspace of any other.

The authors does not provide any proof to the corollary. 
I have trouble identifying the corollary is due to Pitt's theorem.

The following is my attempted proof to the corollary.

> Assume that there is an isomorphism $T:X\to \ell^p$ where $X\subseteq \ell^q$ is a closed subspace.
>   Since $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are both bounded, without loss of generality, we can assume that $1\leq p<q<\infty.$
>   By Pitt's theorem, $T$ is a a compact operator. 
>   Note that 
>   $$B_{\ell^p}\subseteq T(\|T^{-1}\| B_{X})$$
>   where $B_{\ell^p}$ and $B_X$ are the closed unit ball of $\ell^p$ and $X$ respectively. 
>   Since $T$ is compact, by definition of compact operator, $\overline{T(\|T^{-1}\| B_{X})}$ is compact. 
>   Since $T(\|T^{-1}\| B_{X})$ is closed, therefore $T(\|T^{-1}\| B_{X})$ is compact. 
>   Since $B_{\ell^p}$ is a closed subset of a compact set $T(\|T^{-1}\| B_{X}),$ we have $B_{\ell^p}$ is compact as well.
>   This implies that $\ell^p$ is finite-dimensional, contradiction.

Is my proof above correct?

Comment: It's not stated correctly. You need to show that no infinite-dimensional subspace of $\ell_p$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $\ell_q$; a proof of that by contradiction does not begin with $T:\ell_p\to\ell_q$. The same proof applies to prove what you want, you just need to rephrase things.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Noted my mistake. I will change it accordingly. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: No, not right yet. 2.1.16 says there's no iromorphism from a  subspace of $\ell_p$ onto a subspace of $\ell_q$. The current version talks about an isomorphism from a subspace of $\ell_p$ to $\ell_q$...